# How to make an bouncing of element smooth onclick (only using vanilla JS)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make something that is like this:
http://www.lessmilk.com/imgtut/FB1/3.gif

But my square dosen't seem to bounce up properly (it should move up to a certain distance then fall back. Like that in example), especially when it is falling, it stops for  in same position on first click and then requires second click to move up . What did I do wrong or is it not just tuned properly? Can it be done in some other way? Need help and suggestions.

Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Bounce</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      background-color: aqua;
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .square {
      height: 25px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: brown;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" onclick="accelerateUp()">
    <div class="square" style="top:0; left:20px"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var square = document.querySelector('.square');
    var updateInterval, gravitySpeed = 0, gravity = 0.05;
    function accelerateUp() {
      clearInterval(updateInterval)
      gravity = -0.2;
      setTimeout(() => { gravity = 0.05 }, 100)
      updateInterval = setInterval(() => accelerateDown(), 5)
    }

    function accelerateDown() {
      let topValue = parseInt(square.style.top);
      let leftValue = parseInt(square.style.left);
      gravitySpeed += gravity;
      square.style.top = topValue + gravitySpeed + 'px';
      hitBottom();
    }

    function hitBottom() {
      if (parseInt(square.style.top) > 250 || parseInt(square.style.top) < 0) {
        gravitySpeed = 0;
      }
    }

    updateInterval = setInterval(() => accelerateDown(), 5);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you define proper bouncing?

Comment: @Jonathan I just edited (added description) the question,  hope it can help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having an "accelerateUp" you should just consider setting the velocity to a specific/set value on each click OR changing the velocity by a set amount.

I think part of the problem is trying to manage how the acceleration changes as a result of the click hitting the square up, and I think it's just easier to change the velocity and let the acceleration remain constant.

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');
const frameRate = 60; // fps
const yAcceleration = .5;  // change in px / frame
const hitUpForce = -10;
let yVelocity = 0; // px / frame
let yPosition = 0; // px

  
function timeStep() {
  // velocity changes position
  const willHitGround = yPosition + yVelocity > 275
  yPosition = willHitGround ? 275 : yPosition + yVelocity;
  
  // accerlation changes velocity
  yVelocity = willHitGround ? 0 : yVelocity + yAcceleration;
  
  square.style.top = `${yPosition}px`
}

function hitUp() {
  // just set contant velocity as result of hit
  yVelocity = hitUpForce; // Or possibly yVelocity += hitUpForce
}

updateInterval = setInterval(timeStep, 1000/frameRate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Bounce</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .container {
      background-color: aqua;
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .square {
      height: 25px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: brown;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" onclick="hitUp()">
    <div class="square" style="top:0; left:20px"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's totally what I wanted. Thank you so much for your kind and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured it out that I have to reset the gravitySpeed variable to 0 on click (because when falling it's value is negative and that was stoping the ball from jumping on first click). So resetting the variable helped me. I posted the answer here so that it can help someone.

```
function accelerateUp() {
  clearInterval(updateInterval);
  gravitySpeed = 0;
  gravity = -0.2;
  setTimeout(() => { gravity = 0.05 }, 100)
  updateInterval = setInterval(() => accelerateDown(), 5)
}
```